# Convert .OST to .PST

Tags: exchange, pst

I have a .OST file that needs converted to .PST. Exchange server that this file came from has been dbanned.

[This](http://www.addictivetips.com/microsoft-office/how-to-open-pst-and-ost-files-without-outlook-2010/) post about OST & PST viewers seems promising, to view the files... but it states those tools don't have export abilities.

Looking for a needle in a haystack of "trialware", the closest thing I've found is this [Spiceworks topic](http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/190047-is-there-a-freeware-tool-to-convert-ost-to-pst#) with this answer which seems promising:

> Artie Jan 12, 2012 at 3:26 AM You can use outlook to do this recovery
>   but it is a bit of a round-about way. Outlook itself will not let you
>   attach an OST file... What you can do however, is configure Outlook
>   under a separate profile with the user in question's connection (to
>   build the proper authentication certificates). Build it making sure to
>   check the box for Offline use.
>
> Once it is connected, force outlook into offline mode (I usually pull
>   the network connection as well just in case). With outlook forced to
>   offline mode, close outlook. You can now delete the OST file that was
>   just created and replace it with the OST file that you wish to recover
>   from. (NOTE: there is a process from task manager you will have to
>   close that monitors the OST file to not let you delete it, I don't
>   remember off the top of my head what it is, but i remember the name
>   being fairly obvious.)
>
> Start Outlook back up (it should still be in forced offline mode. It
>   will take a few minutes as it builds all the data from the Recovered
>   OST file. Once it is up and running, move EVERYTHING over to a PST
>   file, and you will be good to go.

The thread also has this [brothersoft tool](http://www.brothersoft.com/convert-ost-to-pst-download-68529.html) linked that seems promising. As long as the "Full Trial" is true, I'll be able to use it the one time I need it (Safely in a virtual environment to ensure I don't catch anything).

I'm not really looking for a product recommendation, as much as I'm looking for a solution to a one time issue. There seems to be plenty of (overly advertised) options, so someone who wants to spend $100+ can find a solution. That's a steep price for a one time issue.

I'll try the offline option and the "30 day Trial" option and post an answer if either works, or I'll try other answers if others have better options.

Comment: With the amount of spam we've been getting for OST/PST products, and the shady sites involved, I'm inclined to protect this question right away. Just for clarification, can you list the products you've found and why they don't work? Aren't there any free ones as well?

Comment: I've been doing some looking (spending more time than I should probably) and the most promising ideas have come from here (I'll update question with two options I'll be trying once I get more time tonight): http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/190047-is-there-a-freeware-tool-to-convert-ost-to-pst - most of the other posts I've found seem to revolve around 4-5 revolving spam products.

Comment: @slhck I'm hoping that I can use the OST viewer to get information about the account, then use that to create the offline account and load/export the account offline. Just not sure if I'm barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: You don't need to mark your edits revision history handles that.  Format your question into readable parts and its positioned to be upvoted by me despite its a product recommendation thread :$ we can salvage it though because its a real problem with a solution

Comment: If you find a solution write an answer

Comment: @Ramhound I'm not necessarily looking for a product recommendation, as much as simple answer. The posted "offline" option is an example that doesn't use a product. I only found THAT buried under all the spam, and was wondering if there were any other answers outside of the spam/crapware.

Comment: Those options ate paid software I would imagine

Comment: @slhck I think you should protect it...

Comment: The offline mode is the one I've tried successfully in the past.

Comment: The "brothersoft tool" links to a malicious site (see here: https://mywot.com/en/scorecard/brothersoft.com) and should be removed

Answer (score 1):

This project seems to work perfectly: https://github.com/mkorthof/ost2pst . No restrictions like all the other commercial tools that a Google search turns up.

Answer (score 0):

I've just been asked to move an ost file to another user's Outlook account and instead of doing that I've exported the mail contents of the original Outlook account to a file (pst format) and then imported this file to the target user's Outlook account.